# Bull job not getting triggered in cron[Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, bull, bullmq

I have **multiple** background jobs processors set up using the [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) package like below

```js
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

import Queue from 'bull';

let queue = new Queue('workers', {
  //  settings: { lockDuration: 60 * 20000 },
  defaultJobOptions: {
    removeOnComplete: true
  },
});


queue
  .on('waiting', function(jobId) {
    // A Job is waiting to be processed as soon as a worker is idling.
    // workerLogger.info(`Job ${jobId} waiting to be processed `);
  })
  .on('completed', async(job, result) => {
    workerLogger.info(`Job ID: ${job.id}, Result: ${result}`);
    try {
      const jobbed = await queue.getJob(job.id);
      if (jobbed) {
        await jobbed.remove();
        workerLogger.info(`removed completed job ${job.id}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  })
  .on('failed', function(job, err) {
    workerLogger.error('job ' + job.id + ' in queue failed... ' + err);
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    workerLogger.error('Queue Error... ' + err);
  })
  .on('stalled', function(job) {
    workerLogger.info(
      `stalled job, restarting it again! ${job.queue.name} ${JSON.stringify(
          job.data,
        )} ${job.id} ${job.name}`,
    );
  });

queue.process('healthCheckPing', concurrency, function(job, done) {
  jobs.healthCheckPing(job.data, done);
});

queue.process('test', concurrency, function(job, done) {
  jobs.test(job.data, done);
});
```

I tried running the job based on a Crontime using the [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package but only **one** job gets **processed**, please check the sample below

```
  const cron = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '* * * * *',
    onTick: function() {
      (() => {
        workerLogger.info('Pushing test to queue...');

        queue.add('test');

        queue.add(
          'healthCheckPing',
          {
            jobName: 'test',
          },
        );
      })();
    },
    start: true,
    timeZone: 'Africa/Lagos',
  });
```

I have tried a lot of things to make it work but none seems to work, will list a few below

- running *await queue.obliterate({ force: true });*
- running the worker processor on a separate instance
- add delay to the job - *queue.add('test',{}, {delay:500});*
- adding priority to the job - *queue.add('test',{}, {priority:1});*

Out of the two Jobs(test, healthCheckPing) above, only **one** always gets triggered.

that is, either the job named **test** get processed while the other one is not, or the job name **healthCheckPing** get processed while the other one is not

This is the jobs processor functions below

```js
const jobs = {};

jobs.test = (_, done) => {
  try {
    workerLogger.error('test');

    done(false, 'ok');
  } catch (e) {
    done(e);
  }
};

jobs.healthCheckPing = async({
  jobName
}, done) => {
  try {
    workerLogger.info('health check pinger');

    if (!jobName) throw new Error('uuid not passed');

    // jobname is the slug for monitor

    // use pingkey to negate between staging and prod monitors
    const pingKey = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ?
      process.env.STAGING_HEALTH_CHECK_KEY :
      process.env.PROD_HEALTH_CHECK_KEY;

    const url = `https://hc-ping.com/${pingKey}/${jobName}`;

    await axios.get(url);

    done(false, `pinged ${jobName}!`);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
};

export default jobs;
```

> This code works perfectly on my local machine, but this issue only
> occurs when on production. The node server is run using pm2(cluster mode, instance = 1)

Comment: Above code works fine with just a simple `done()` call in the job processor functions. Since you did not post the code  - that is where probably where the problem is.

Comment: thanks, @madflow, but I doubt if that is the issue. I have edited the question to include the functions

Comment: @madflow, the code works perfectly on my local machine. The issue occurs on the sever when using pm2

Answer (score 0):

the issue was because I was using the **same** queue name in another service **sharing** the same Redis connection,

```
let queue = new Queue('workers', {
  //  settings: { lockDuration: 60 * 20000 },
  defaultJobOptions: {
    removeOnComplete: true
  },
});
```

**changing** workers to something else fixed the issue